# hiding entire pages in an r markdown document

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown

I have the r markdown document below. I would like to hide page 2 if parameter "P" is not equal to A.

So the result would be if parameter P != A then only 3 pages are produced.

Is this possible somehow?

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: 
  pdf_document:
    toc: yes
params:
  P: A
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

\newpage


## PAGE2

this is text for page 2

this is text for page 2

```{r cars}
summary(cars)
```

\newpage


## PAGE3

this is text for page 3

```{r pressure, echo=FALSE}
plot(pressure)
```

\newpage 

## PAGE4

this is text for page 4
````

Comment: i'd put it in a separate Rmd file and use knit_child to insert it as a chunk with conditional output on/off.

Comment: Is there anyway to do it with one rmd file?

Answer (score 0):

You could comment the section out based on P value. Here is a bit of a hackish way to do it: surround the section with `\iffalse`/`\fi`. Note that the R code inside the section still needs to be valid for this to work (it will be compiled by knitr, but ignored by latex).

````
```{r, echo=FALSE, results='asis'}
if(params$P != "A") 
  cat("\\iffalse")
```

## PAGE2

this is text for page 2

this is text for page 2

```{r cars}
summary(cars)
```

\newpage

```{r, echo=FALSE, results='asis'}
if(params$P != "A") 
  cat("\\fi")
```
````